# Не получается корректно отобразить, отправленное изображение в канал Discord с помощью requests

Tags: python, requests, discord

Моя задача состоит в том что бы спарсить с мегамаркета определенную информацию и отправить ее в дискорд канал с помощью requests.Я получаю src данного изображения, но когда отправляю ссылку в нужный мне канал, она не раскрывается как изображение, а так и остается ссылкой. Если попробовать скопировать эту ссылку и отправить ее руками, то она сразу же станет изображением. [image: вторая ссылка является ссылкой на изображение]
Отсюда и возникает вопрос, можно ли как то это исправить.

Comment: а можно пожалуйста код?

Comment: @ForevorBase. добавил код к вопросу.

Comment: Попробуй или через библиотеку discord.py или через хуки